# Mysql2::Error: Can't read dir of './ppml_development/' (errno: 13): SHOW TABLES

Tags: mysql, coffeescript, npm

I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't read dir of './site_development/' (errno: 13): SHOW TABLES
```

whenever I try to query the db of any of my rails apps that use mysql.  The same error shows up within the mysql> env when I log in as Rails user and SHOW TABLES;. This problem surfaced after installing node, npm, and coffee-script.  I think the problem is a permissions issue as both npm and mysql are in /usr/local/.  Per the instructions in Trevor Burnham's Coffeescript book, I used the following commands during the install process:

```
sudo mkdir -p $PREFIX/{share/man,bin,lib/node,include/node}
sudo chown -R $USER $PREFIX/{share/man,bin,lib/node,include/node}
sudo chown -R dowdjj local
```

When I run:

```
sudo ls -l
```

within /usr/local/mysql/data it shows root:wheel for the permissions for all databases, including ppml_development.  I'm guessing this is an easy fix, but just out of my league as a newbie.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, issue is resolved.  Since mysql is also in /usr/local/ the "sudo chown -R dowdjj local" overwrote the original owner of all the mysql files, which was "_mysql". Once I corrected that all was fine.

Comment: To clarify for anyone coming across this question, those instructions aren't actually given in my book; the book links to [this list of techniques for installing Node and npm], and some of those involve `chown`.

Comment: Meant to say "[this list of techniques for installing Node and npm](https://gist.github.com/579814)".